# Перетаскивание кастомного конрола

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь использовать библиотеку `gong-wpf-dragdrop` для перемещения контролов внутри списка. В библиотеке есть возможность создать шаблон перетаскиваемого элемента:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True">
<dd:DragDrop.DragAdornerTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        ...
    </DataTemplate>
</dd:DragDrop.DragAdornerTemplate>
```

но как сделать так, что бы при перетаскивании захватывался мой `UserControl`?

Comment: Ну напишите вместо трёх точек `<local:MyUserControl/>`

Comment: @АндрейNOP это, конечно, здорово, но как мне всю инфу перенести? А если в одном из контролов будет уникальный объект?

Comment: Так же как и в ListBox отображаете – с помощью привязок. Как я понял, захватываемый и перетаскиваемый объекты имеют одинаковый DataContext, поэтому проблем быть не должно

Comment: Приведите минимальный самодостаточный пример с UserControl, иллюстрирующий проблему

Comment: @АндрейNOP ну да, про привязку я и не вспомнил. Только один момент, в контроле есть `CheckBox`, который во время перетаскивания не привязывается к оригиналу, т.е. `IsChecked` стоит по умолчанию, а не тот, который установлен внутри контрола. Можно это обойти, не строя дикие привязки через свойства?

Comment: Пока не знаю, добавьте код в вопрос

Comment: @АндрейNOP добавил

Comment: Эээ, это минимальный код? Здесь каждая строчка важна? [MCVE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @АндрейNOP минимальный код - <UserControl><Grid><CheckBox /></Grid></UserControl>

Comment: И где у вас там привязка? С привязками у меня всё работает: https://pastebin.com/hzYYRc28

Comment: @ Виталий, разобрались?

Comment: @АндрейNOP неа, у меня при той же системе привязок не сработало. Отложил на потом.